# What is the fastest way to calculate partial SVD of a huge matrix using Python libraries?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scipy, svd

I have a large (500k x 300k) dense matrix for which I need to find the top approx. 50 singular values (high accuracy is not important) and corresponding singular vectors. I have access to Amazon SageMaker instances which enables me to use up to 256GB RAM, however the matrix takes up about 600GB so it cannot be kept in memory.

To circumvent this issue, calculating matrix-vector products with this matrix is fairly fast and parallelizable using Tensorflow.

I have looked into some related questions such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41259/how-to-compute-svd-of-a-huge-sparse-matrix 
, however the whole workflow is implemented in Python/Tensorflow and therefore it would be a significant overhead to use R.

First, I tried using `numpy.linalg.svd` which can utilize multi-core execution, however as I mentioned I cannot fit the whole matrix into memory and I don't need a full SVD (which is the only option since it uses LAPACK).

Second, I tried `scipy.sparse.linalg.svds`, which uses ARPACK and takes a `LinearOperator` instead of a matrix. This solved the memory issues, however this ARPACK implementation seems to use a single core for SVD (even though the matrix-vector multiplication runs on multiple cores) and therefore extremely slow. The fact that the matrix is dense makes the problem much worse.

I would really appreciate any input how problems like this are usually tackled. I might have overlooked some built-in functionality of `numpy` or `scipy`, but I am also open to other practical algorithms, not available in Python libraries, for partial SVD that might help with the memory issue and would do the job in a reasonable amount of time (couple of days maximum).
Thank you for the answer in advance!

Comment: [Here is an article](https://simplyml.com/benchmarking-the-singular-value-decomposition/) benchmarking a few other packages for SVD, if you're not dead-set on using scipy

Comment: Maybe [this](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2015/06/26/Complex-Graphs) helps. The keyword *out of core* is probably what i would base my research on.